# Setting focus to a textbox when a function is called

Tags: javascript, focus, html-input

I currently have a textbox in my aspx:

```
 <input type="text" id="myTextbox"  value="" />
```

I was wondering if I could set the focus (put my cursor in that text box) every time my JavaScript method is called. I was hoping it would work along the lines of this:

```
function setFocus() {
    document.getElementById("myTextbox").Focus();
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Invoke the lowercase `.focus()` function:

```
function setFocus() {
    document.getElementById("myTextbox").focus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, All the examples showed uppercase so i just assumed when it didnt work that i was just implementing it wrong. I'll mark you as the answer once it allows me to. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this won't work if you're trying it out in the console. For Chrome at least.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
function setFocus(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).focus();
```

}

In this way, your function becomes reusable.
Just pass the ID of the html element to be given the focus when you call the function.

M.