# On load put cursor in form field (customized Google form)

Tags: forms, cursor, google-forms

Sorry for the newbie question:

I have looked at several posts on how to get a cursor to automatically be in a particular form field, but I cannot find an answer to my specific problem.  I am working from a Google form that I've done some customization on, so I can't find the elements that the other posts are referring to. I would like to have the cursor automatically appear in the Scan Barcode field on: http://people.virginia.edu/~ag5vy/catstats.html.

Comment: have you looked at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543967/setting-focus-to-a-textbox-when-a-function-is-called